# Why won't my cart increment counter work?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cart

I want the count to increase in the navbar for every time the "add to cart" button is clicked on an item, but I can't see why my code isn't working, when I click add to cart button currently the counter does not increase. If anyone could tell me what I'm missing or give me a better solution to what I have I'd appreciate it, thanks!

```js
$('.addCart').on('click', function() {
  console.log(completedIncrements.indexOf(this.id));

  if (completedIncrements.indexOf(this.id) == -1) {
    var count = parseInt($("#count").text());
    $("#count").html(count + 1);

    completedIncrements.push(this.id);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="shoppingcart.html" class="cart">Shopping Cart (<span id="count">0</span>)</a>
  <a href="shop.html" class="right">Shop</a>
  <a href="contactus.html" class="right">Contact Us</a>
</div>
<a href="shoe1.html"><img id="shoe3" img src="images/shoe1.jpg" alt="shoe1">
<div id="cart1" class="addCart" href="#"><button>Add to cart</button></div>
<a href="shoe2.html"><img id="shoe4" img src="images/shoe2.jpg" alt="shoe2">
<div id="cart2" class="addCart" href="#"><button>Add to cart</button></div>
```

Comment: Where is `completedIncrements` defined? Also, your HTML appears malformed. You are missing your end anchor tags (`</a>`).

Comment: well your code only adds it if the item is not in the cart. And you are adding the button id to the array, not the item id.

Answer (score -1):

I just checked your code. The completeIncrements is throwing error in the console and preventing the execution of your logic. Please give information about that or else use the code below to solve it.

```
$('.addCart').on('click', function() {

    var count = parseInt($("#count").text());
    $("#count").html(count + 1);

   
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
$('.addCart').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var completedIncrements =0;
 
  
    var count = parseInt($("#count").text());
    $("#count").html(count + 1);

   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="shoppingcart.html" class="cart">Shopping Cart (<span id="count">0</span>)</a>
  <a href="shop.html" class="right">Shop</a>
  <a href="contactus.html" class="right">Contact Us</a>
</div>
<a href="shoe1.html"><img id="shoe3" img src="images/shoe1.jpg" alt="shoe1">
<div id="cart1" class="addCart" href="#"><button>Add to cart</button></div>
<a href="shoe2.html"><img id="shoe4" img src="images/shoe2.jpg" alt="shoe2">
<div id="cart2" class="addCart" href="#"><button>Add to cart</button></div>
```

Use prevent default function so that link should not be refreshed and also removed unnecessary code

```js
$('.addCart').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();      
    var count = parseInt($("#count").text());
    $("#count").html(count + 1);       
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```